# Pushing React components into a React state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am experimenting with React:
I have 2 arrays (array1 and array2) containing some words. 
I would like to initialize my React state array called "sentences" by looping the 2 arrays (array1 and array2) and pushing a component "Sentence" into the state array at each iteration. This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Sentence from "./Sentence.js";

var array1 = ["hello", "some", "words", "house", "garden", "car"];
var array2 = ["other", "bag", "of", "words", "oh", "yeah"];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      sentences: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
        let newArray = this.state.sentences.slice();
        newArray.push( <Sentence word1={array1[i]} word2={array2[j]} /> );
        this.setState({ sentences: newArray });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.sentences[0]}
        {this.state.sentences[1]}
        {this.state.sentences[2]}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**And this is Sentence.js:**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Sentence extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      word1: this.props.word1,
      word2: this.props.word2
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        First word: {this.state.word1}
        <br />
        Second word: {this.state.word2}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Sentence;
```

**However, in browser, I only see:**

```
First word: car
Second word: yeah
```

**My desired result would be to see the first and second word for the first 3 components of the state array (sentences).**

Comment: `setState` is async. `this.state.sentences` won't be updated inside the loop. Build the Array first and then push it all at once.

Comment: Even if it weren't async, you'd keep overwriting the state with your last Sentence. https://codesandbox.io/s/7382nzzzr0 (check index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is async. `this.state.sentence` won't be updated inside the loop.

Either Build the Array first and then push it all at once.

```
let sentences = this.state.sentences.slice();

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    sentences.push( <Sentence word1={array1[i]} word2={array2[j]} /> );
  }
}

this.setState({ sentences: sentences });
```

or use the callback version of `setState`

```
for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        sentences: [
          ...state.sentences, 
          <Sentence word1={array1[i]} word2={array2[j]} />
        ]
      }
    });
  }
}
```

---

And as a sidenote, your Sentences Component doesn't need a state:

```
const Sentence = ({ word1, word2 }) => (
  <div>
    First word: {word1}
    <br />
    Second word: {word2}
  </div>
);
export default Sentence;
```

I'd build it like this

```
var array1 = ["hello", "some", "words", "house", "garden", "car"];
var array2 = ["other", "bag", "of", "words", "oh", "yeah"];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = { pairs: [] };
    for(const word1 of array1) {
      for(const word2 of array2) {
        this.state.pairs.push({ word1, word2 });
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{
        this.state.pairs.map(words => <Sentence ...words />)
      }</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding  `this.state.pairs.push({ word1, word2 });`
Shouldn't this.state be treated as if it were immutable?

Comment: @Tom, you're right I'm not in the constructor anymore. fixed it.